# Are hardware-related questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags

The question [What kind of hardware and software are required to build an AI system?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/16525/2444) asks for hardware recommendations. However, there exists already a site, namely https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com, for this specific purpose. The following question [What is the reason AMD Radeon is not widely used for machine learning and deep learning?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/16538/2444) should also be probably closed as off-topic, for a similar reason.

Currently, our on-topic page does not apparently say that hardware-related questions are on-topic. We even have the tags [hardware](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [hardware-evaluation](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-evaluation), which probably should not even exist. All hardware-related questions should be implementation-related questions, so they should be off-optic here.